# Using search_fullarchive from rtweet with multiple operators (sandbox PREMIUM)

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am trying to use `search_fullarchive` from the `rtweet` package on *sandbox* PREMIUM with these exact search operators `park OR parks`, `lang:en` and `point_radius:[51.5047 0.1278 25mi]`. I have tried the following

```
test2 <- search_fullarchive(q = "park OR parks lang:en point_radius:[51.5074 0.1278 25mi]", n = 100, fromDate = "202003150000", toDate = "202003172359", env = "research", parse = TRUE, token = ActiveTravel_token)
```

The returned `test2` object is a `tbl_df` filtered only by `park OR parks`. I've checked [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/operators-by-product) and as a *sandbox* PREMIUM user I should be able to filter by `lang:` and `point_radius:`

Could someone please help me get the filtering to also match the other two operators `lang:en` and `point_radius:[51.5047 0.1278 25mi]`.

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes,
Irena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as wrapping the text in parentheses, with the whitespace acting as a logical AND for the other fields.

`q = "(park OR parks) lang:en point_radius:[51.5074 0.1278 25mi]"`

However, I've just tried this search and at the moment, it returns zero Tweets within that point radius over that date range. I substituted in another point radius (the Boulder, CO example from the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/guides/using-premium-operators), `point_radius:[-105.27346517 40.01924738 10.0mi]`, and it successfully brought back Tweets that matched the search parameters.

Comment: Thank you Andy! Yes, very strange, I had the same issue using q = "(park OR parks) lang:en point_radius:[51.5074 0.1278 25mi]" as well. Like you said, I just used the Boulder CO coordinates and it returned only 4 observations. In the previous try I had 100 observations matching "park OR parks".

Answer (score 1):

As to finding very few tweets. The point radius-operator will only return tweets that were geotagged manually by the user at the time of the tweet, and then only within a small area of maximum 25 miles. Only a small fraction of tweets are geo-tagged. You will probably have more luck with the place: operator. It will also return tweets by people who have the "place" you search for, set in their profile.

Comment: Thanks @d_fornis and @Andy, your advice solved both issues. I could sucessfully retrieve 100 observations for London per request using this code: `test4 <- search_fullarchive(q = "(park OR parks) lang:en place:London", n = 100, fromDate = "202003150000", toDate = "202003172359", env = "research", parse = TRUE, token = ActiveTravel_token)` Apologies I can't up-vote both answers (I am a newbie!). Stay safe!